# Li-ion vs Li-Po batteries cut-off protection

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, lipo, low-battery, lithium-ion

I am confused with the differences between Li-ion batteries (like 18650) and Li-Po (the flat ones).

I know that basically they are both lithium ion, but when I want to buy I see that LiPos have always undervoltage protection, and they should not be used if voltage is <3.0V, whereas 18650 Li-ions can be with **or** **without** protection circuitry and the cut-off is around 2.5V-2.6V (if there is protection circuit.)

Is my statement correct?

In general, can I replace a Li-ion with LiPo in a circuit?

Comment: Radio control models buy Lipos ALL THE TIME (the flat ones that look like bags) without undervoltage protection. It's just a matter of how raw of a product you are buying. I'll bet all the batteries you're looking at with built-in undervoltage protection are very small batteries.

Comment: i have two big 18650 li-ions and i have bought them with protection..they are more than 3000mAh

Comment: Pretty big. In any case, you can get them easily without built-in protection.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a comparison chart from [Electronic Design](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21806525/whats-the-better-battery-for-your-portablesli-ion-or-li-poly):

[image]

And here's another from [Benzo Energy](http://www.benzoenergy.com/blog/post/better-battery-for-smartphone.html):

[image]

These may not be all inclusive, but whether you can replace one with the other depends on which of the attributes are being utilized.  For a phone, the non-cylindrical form factor and lack of liquid electrolyte are relatively irreplacable advantages.  In addition to this for a device frequently held close to the body and unmonitored, the cells inflate their plastic bag in most failure modes and push the back off the phone, making it clear that maintenance is necessary, typically without a fire.

Generally, you shouldn't use a lithium ion battery without protection, and ones sold without protection are for use in packs with overall protection or devices that provide protection separately.  You can also greatly extend their lifespan by not using their full charge range.

It's also worth noting that you cannot replace chemistry or with a smaller cell without evaluating the charging and protection circuits.  Switching to a larger cell may also be a risk of overcharging because cut off current is based on capacity, so you have to evaluate the charger circuit in that case as well.  Thanks Russel McMahon for the correction.

Comment: May be worth noting that a higher than original capacity battery may be OVER charged by an original charger as acceptable termination current will be a lower fraction of the cell's capacity.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hmm it's something that I've gotten away with quite a few times, but that does sound intuitively bad.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: At least from my experience, the battery charge circuit monitors the battery voltage to keep from over charging the battery. When the battery voltage reaches a predetermined value (let's say 4.1 VDC), then the charger switches from constant-current to constant-voltage mode to prevent the battery from being overcharged. A higher than original capacity battery will just take longer to charge. There should not be a risk of over charging if the battery protection circuitry is working properly. https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/a-designer-guide-fast-lithium-ion-battery-charging

Comment: @Grace the battery can be overcharged because the constant voltage charge mode cut off happens when the charge current reaches 1/10th of the C (mAh capacity) of the battery.  If for example, you double the capacity of the battery but don't modify the charger circuit, the circuit will keep charging until charge current reaches 1/20th of C because it's still set to the cut out current of the smaller cell, which will result in an overcharge.  I suspect the damage done is more a reduction in MTBF than a guaranteed fireball as long as you don't increase capacity too much.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Hi, Just FYI *Grace* originally posted as an answer - but since it wasn't an answer, I've converted it to a comment, as it was clearly addressed in response to your comment. However, due to only having 1 point currently, *Grace* cannot currently write further comments in reply.

Comment: @SamGibson Ooooo so thats what the blue diamond does.  Grace watch for easy to research and answer non-school questions and write good, quick answers to a few of them to build a bit of rep to comment.  You also get 2 points per edit IIRC, so you can also work on the queues to build a bit of rep.  Read the site rules and be careful not to break them if you can avoid it.  Downvotes are weaker than upvotes, but if someone sees a problem being caused by a site rule being broken, they'll either write and tell you or just downvote or both.  Building enough rep to comment is easy if you're careful.

Comment: @Grace Another option is to provide better answers to an old question, but be careful doing this as it will bump them to the top of the queue temporarily so we don't want a flood of too many of them all at once.  Be aware that people come and go so some people in old questions can't be reached, so you can write in response to OP, but don't write in a way that expects a response.  Finally, you can get points for questions too, but that can be more challenging.  Points get awarded for some combination of new, interesting, good effort, good technical writing but truly new questions are rare.

Comment: If you're finding difficulty finding good questions that haven't been asked, there is the category of "do my project for me" questions.  Like "How do I build and program a raspberry pi based shift register type LED controller".  They aren't favored around here, but if you're capable and willing to answer the question yourself, you *can* write this type of Q&A as a guide on how to do something. Make sure you post the answer quickly and ask the question in a professional way.  I don't remember who, but recently there was some new engineer I saw doing this to build initial rep.

Comment: @GRace Overcharging can occur as per KH's explanation above. His answer is correct but I'll put some figures on it to make it clearer. I'll also use an extreme case. Charge control is internal to a device. A single cell LiIon 1 Ah battery is installed and specified to charge at 1C with a termination current of 0.5C - ie the battery charges to 4.2V at 1A and then goes into a CV mode at 4.2V so current reduces until the 0.5A limit is reached. NOW, replace the 1Ah cell with a 5 Ah cell. The battery is STILL charged at 1A until 4.2V is reached (taking about 5 times as long). Now ...

Comment: ... the cell is put into CV mode at 4.2V and charged until current again reduces to 0.6=5A. HOWEVER as the battery capacity is 5x larger the 0.5A now represents 0.1C . This may not seem overly significant, but it often is. Terminating charge at 0.5C gives a reasonably full charge. Terminating at 0.1C gives a very very full charge indeed. The cell is MUCH more stressed mechanically and the cycle life may be reduced by a factor of several times - for relatively little gain in capacity. This is not usually visible externally until the battery starts to swell at far fewer cycles than expected.