# Can Li-ion BMSs be used with Li-po batteries?

Tags: lithium-ion, circuit-protection, bms, undervoltage

I'm building a robot that's running on a 12S, 10400 mAh Li-po. Because of obvious reasons, the system requires a protection circuit.

Can I purchase this 13S (which I suppose works with lower S values too) [100 A Li-ion BMS from Daly](https://www.ebay.com/itm/314617382739) and use it as protection for my circuit? It is made for Li-ion, so will it work?

All I need is to have an adjustable cut-off voltage, so that when the battery goes below 3.6 or 3.7 V/cell, it is disconnected from the system.

The expected current draw is 70 A (yes, the robot will operate for just a couple of minutes).

Comment: Lithium polymer is a subset of lithium ion. Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/557702/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/562601/2028, and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/678846/2028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Li-Ion BMSs be used with LiPo batteries?

What you call a "LiPo" cell **IS** a Li-ion cell. It happens to be in a pouch, but it is still a Li-ion cell.

Yes, that BMS will work, because the BMS doesn't know or care whether the Li-ion cells are housed in a cylinder, a box, or a pouch.

Unfortunately, there is this myth out there that somehow pouch cells are a different chemistry than other Li-ion cells. Only the enclosure is different. Inside, they  all the same technology: intercalation of Lithium ions through a liquid electrolyte. Contrary to popular belief, pouch cells do not use a polymer electrolyte.

A Li-ion BMS can be used with any Li-ion cells, whether cylindrical (e.g., 18650), prismatic, or pouch (which you call "LiPo"). As long as it for the correct voltage (usually 3.6~3.7 V nominal).

[image: All these cells are Li-ion]

{Source: me}

There are 3 groups of chemistries:

- LTO: 2.5 V
- LFP (LiFePO4): 3.25 V nominal
- All others (LCO, NMC, NCA, LMO): 3.6 or 3.7 V nominal

A BMS for one group will work with any cell in that group.

Answer (score 0):

Nooo! The difference between Li-ion and Li-pos has nothing to do with packaging! Li-po batteries are lithium-ion POLYMER.

The major difference between the two batteries: a lithium-ion battery uses a liquid/gel electrolyte between the anode and cathode, while a lithium-polymer battery uses a polymer electrolyte (solid or colloidal) and an organic electrolyte.

Li-pos can not handle as low a voltage as lithium-ion batteries can. It will be destroyed when using a BMS made for "normal" Li-ions.